# Deploying a simple java file in WLS/JDeveloper

Tags: java, deployment, jdeveloper

We have a scenario where we have a java code which calls some API's to send/receive XML to the target system. This code works locally on the VM. Our client needs to call this code in order to retrieve the information via http call to WLS server.
What we are trying to figure out is which kind of project do I need to create in JDeveloper in order to deploy it on WLS so client can call the java file via http.
I have spent few days reading WLS documentation but couldn't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated?

SL

Comment: In order to help you, you need to show a minimum of effort/code in your question. Please have a look at this link on how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks RoyaumelX!
I got the answer and it's probably the Java Servlets which would do it for me. I will close it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider developing this as a Web Service (SOAP or REST).
For example - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_web_services/tut_web_services.html